# Springboot application is stopping after closing the putty in unix box

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to deploy the jar/war file in unix box and it should not stop after closing putty.

Steps tried:

1. Created jar/war file from Springboot project
2. Login to Unix box with root user
3. Created a Project folder in /opt path
4. Copied the jar/war file in Project folder
5. Executed below command to run the application in putty:
   Command: java -jar myapplication.jar
6. Application is running fine but issue comes when i close my putty. Application shutdowns.

Any suggestions...

Comment: you need to learn `nohup` command (alternatively it is possible to run boot applications as [service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment.installing))

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your custom service in your machine

EX: In Linux we use `sudo systemctl start MySQL` like that you have to create,

Please refer to this [documentation](https://www.auroria.io/spring-boot-as-systemd-service/) which will help you to create your own.

EX: `sudo systemctl start my_java_spring_service`

I hope it helps!